# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token - React Vite

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy trabajando con React Vite y Strapi, venia trabajando bien y me encontre con este error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token el cual me informa que esta en la primer linea del componente FormularioLogin.jsx, como se envidencia en la foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo del componente mencionado es el siguiente, pero el venia funcionando bien y no se hizo ninguna modificacion en ese componente:

```
import React from "react"

function FormularioLogin() {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="mb-4">
        <label
            className="text-white"
            htmlFor="usuario"
        >Usuario:</label>
        <input 
            id="usuario"
        type="text"
        className="mt-2 block w-full p-3 bg-transparent border-2 border-solid border-white         rounded-xl placeholder-white"
        placeholder="Ingrese su usuario"
        name="usuario"
    />
</div>
<div className="mb-4">
    <label
        className="text-white"
        htmlFor="password"
    >Contraseña:</label>
    <input 
        id="password"
        type="password"
        className="mt-2 block w-full p-3 bg-transparent border-2 border-solid border-white rounded-xl placeholder-white"
        placeholder="Ingrese la contraseña"
        name="password"
    />
</div>

</>
  )
}

export default FormularioLogin
```

El package.json hice un cambio que fue quitarle el ^, pero seguia con el mismo error entonces lo deje como estana y es el siguiente:

```
    {
  "name": "sanavit",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "rc-progress": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: En el error que aparece en WebDevTools, dale click a FormularioLogin.jsx, para que veas especificamente a que token / elemento se refiere

Comment: Ya lo arregle, era en un componente que estaba importando unas imagenes y solo borre la improtacion y la volvi hacer arriba de todos los import y ya

Answer (score 0):

Hola a mi me a traído de cabeza, al final borre los node-modules y el yarn.lock, volvi a intalar todo y magicamente funciono

Es curioso que me afectaba a una pestaña en Chrome, pero si lo cargaba en otra pestaña en otra sesión diferente, tiraba

Espero que sea de ayuda